# DynamoDB schema design for timeseries data without clear partition key

Tags: rust, amazon-dynamodb

I'm playing around with dynamodb and CRUD operations for a small app that I'm tinkering with.

tl;dr I have a dataset that is

```
pub struct TransferOnly {
    pub ts: String,
    pub block: String,
    pub from: String,
    pub to: String,
    pub value: String,
}
```

where

```
ts = timestamp in unix
block = hex string 
from = hex string
to = hex string
value = hex string.
```

We definitely want ts as our sort key but we are unsure what to use as our partition key. Block is not unique (neither is ts nor the combination of both), from and to are non-unique per block and neither is value.

We want to optimize for searching and aggregating froms and tos (ie. everyone that sent money to x, total money sent to x by y from) between certain dates.

We're using Dynamodb b/c timestream doesn't have a rust sdk. What's an optimal database schema design here?

Comment: First, you need to list every access pattern. Yes, all of them. Include expected item counts/sizes being returned. Also explain how you’ll load and update the data. And at what rate you’ll do the queries and updates. All that impacts the design.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following in the link [DynamoDBTimeSeries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-time-series.html)

Copying few contents from the URL.

The following design pattern often handles this kind of scenario effectively:

Create one table per period, provisioned with the required read and write capacity and the required indexes.

Before the end of each period, prebuild the table for the next period. Just as the current period ends, direct event traffic to the new table. You can assign names to these tables that specify the periods they have recorded.

As soon as a table is no longer being written to, reduce its provisioned write capacity to a lower value (for example, 1 WCU), and provision whatever read capacity is appropriate. Reduce the provisioned read capacity of earlier tables as they age. You might choose to archive or delete the tables whose contents are rarely or never needed.